# Fill pandas data frame using .append()

Tags: python, pandas, append, dataframe

I have a dataframe with a column containing comma separated strings. What I want to do is separate them by comma, count them and append the counted number to a new data frame. If the column contains a list with only one element, I want to differentiate wheather it is a string or an integer. If it is an integer, I want to append the value 0 in that row to the new df. 
My code looks as follows:

```
def decide(dataframe):
    df=pd.DataFrame()

    for liste in DataFrameX['Column']:
        x=liste.split(',')
        if len(x) > 1:
            df.append(pd.Series([len(x)]), ignore_index=True)
        else:
            #check if element in list is int
            for i in x:
                try:
                    int(i)
                    print i
                    x = []

                    df.append(pd.Series([int(len(x))]), ignore_index=True)
                except:
                    print i
                    x = [1]
                    df.append(pd.Series([len(x)]), ignore_index=True)
    return df
```

The Input data look like this:

```
   C1  
0  a,b,c
1  0
2  a
3  ab,x,j
```

If I now run the function with my original dataframe as input, it returns an empty dataframe. Through the print statement in the try/except statements I could see that everything works. The problem is appending the resulting values to the new dataframe. What do I have to change in my code? If possible, please do not give an entire different solution, but tell me what I am doing wrong in my code so I can learn.

******************UPDATE************************************

I edited the code so that it can be called as lambda function. It looks like this now:

```
def decide(x):
    For liste in DataFrameX['Column']:

        x=liste.split(',')
        if len(x) > 1:
            x = len(x)
            print x
        else:
            #check if element in list is int
            for i in x:
                try:
                    int(i)
                    x = []
                    x = len(x)
                    print x

                except: 
                    x = [1]
                    x = len(x)
                    print x
```

And I call it like this:

```
df['Count']=df['C1'].apply(lambda x: decide(x))
```

It prints the right values, but the new column only contains `None`.

Any ideas why?

Comment: As a general rule, dataframe are not made to be iterated with a for loop, you should use something like df.apply(lambda x: len(x)),

Is the problem that you are iterating DataFrameX but you pass dataframe to the function? you should post your input, and raise an error in your try/except to see the problem

Comment: thought of that, but did not know how to build in the if + try except statements. But i'll try.

Comment: You don't need to use a lambda, simply pass any function you like to `apply`.

Comment: @karlson you are correct, but I think the lambda is more clear on what is passed

Comment: @user1883737 But you can't have try-except blocks in lambdas, which is why the OP might want to use a normal function.

Comment: @sequence_hard you can create a function for the if+try and use it in the lambda, like:

def myfunciton(mystring):
     /*your code  with the if+ try*/
    return yourvalue

newdf = df.apply(lambda x: myfunciton(x)

Comment: @karlson but you can have a function that you use in your lambda, and that's definitely the way to do it. sequence_hard if you post me your input I can write a relevant example

Comment: Added an example of input data :-)

Answer (score 0):

This is a good start, it could be simplified, but I think it works as expected.

```
#I have a dataframe with a column containing comma separated strings.
df = pd.DataFrame({'data': ['apple, peach', 'banana, peach, peach, cherry','peach','0']})

# What I want to do is separate them by comma, count them and append the counted number to a new data frame.
df['data'] = df['data'].str.split(',')
df['count'] = df['data'].apply(lambda row: len(row))
# If the column contains a list with only one element
df['first'] = df['data'].apply(lambda row: row[0])
# I want to differentiate wheather it is a string or an integer
df['first'] = pd.to_numeric(df['first'], errors='coerce')
# if the element in x is an integer, len(x) should be set to zero 
df.loc[pd.notnull(df['first']), 'count'] = 0
# Dropping temp column
df.drop('first', 1, inplace=True)
df

                                data  count
0                    [apple,  peach]      2
1  [banana,  peach,  peach,  cherry]      4
2                            [peach]      1
3                                [0]      0
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My problem is that when the integer 0 is in the list that is counted, len(row) will still give me the number 1 in the dataframe, where I want 0.

Comment: Is the need to replace by the integer in the list only for zero or for all integer values ?

Comment: if the element in x is an integer, len(x) should be set to zero